# How to retrieve dropdown items from an observable?

Tags: angular-reactive-forms

How would you retrieve dropdown items from an observable in `@rxweb/reactive-dynamic-forms` ?

how do you inject service in `FormControlConfig` subclass? shared code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bs5yqt-nmzcwj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For injecting custom services into the dynamic form control source model you have to pass the respective service into the argument of model configuration.

## Step 1

Create a Service according to your need, I am creating fake ConfigService.

```js
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  configUrl = 'assets/config.json';

getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
}
```

## Step 2

Let's create a Model, which is extended with FormControlConfig for async source binding.

```js
import { FormControlConfig } from "@rxweb/reactive-dynamic-forms"
import { ConfigService } from "./config.service"
export class SourceAsyncConditionalModel extends FormControlConfig{
constructor(fieldConfig: { [key: string]: any }, public controlsConfig: { [key: string]: FormControlConfig },notificationId:number,private configService:ConfigService){
super(fieldConfig,controlsConfig,notificationId);

}
    filter() {

        let promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
/// call the service
      if(this.configService)
      this.configService.getConfig();
        });
    }

}
```

If you see the above the code where I have defined four parameters. The first three parameters are used in FormControlControl and the fourth parameter we can use in the model instance.

## Step 3

Now, we have to pass the parameter with respective model. See the below code :

```js
this.dynamicFormConfiguration = {
      controlConfigModels: [{ modelName: 'sourceAsync', model: SourceAsyncConditionalModel,arguments:[this.configService] }],
    }
    this.dynamicFormBuildConfig = this.formBuilder.formGroup(this.serverData, this.dynamicFormConfiguration);
```

Here is the [working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjw5he-dbb2gb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)